# How am i getting 12Mbps speed internet on a 10baseT Ethernet?

Tags: ethernet, switch, gigabit-ethernet

I've opted for an internet connection of 12Mbps, I still do get both 12 up and down, but my isp has plugged a 10baseT wire and I've learned that max speed on ethernet to the base of twisted pair is 10Mbps. So how am I getting 12 up and 12 down?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what "my isp has plugged a 10baseT wire" means? Please explain to me what 10baseT wire means to you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a "standard" ethernet patch cable such as this one:

[image]

Then, depending on the quality of the cable and the devices connected at either end you can get up to 1000Mbps (1Gbps) down it.

10BaseT refers to the ethernet devices connecting over the cable and the cable is more commonly referred to by its "category". Standard 100Mbps cable is Cat5 (category 5) and Cat5e or Cat6 cable can support 1Gbps and beyond.

10BaseT is not a cable designation.

Most modern network cards use 1000BaseTX (gigabit) ethernet transceivers.